# CCSpriteFrameCache or CCSprite? - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am making my first game and so far my only problem is memory usage (I haven't payed the developer fee so I am running it in the simulator).  So far it is taking up about 23MB, from what I've read that is way to much.  Is this true?  First, in my main menu my biggest problem is my background, it is taking up 2MB+ of memory. Is that ok? Second, the background in my gamescene is also taking up 2MB+. Is that ok? Third, I have 2 CCSpriteFrameCaches's, one has 55 .PNG files and the other has 12.  The one with the 55 images takes up about 9MB of memory. Does that sound normal? The second one takes up about 3MB. Does that sound normal?

The 55 images aren't added to the layer until a button is pressed (which then takes up even more memory about 7MB, not sure why).  Then when the second button is pressed the first image is removed and the second image is added.  Then, when the first button is pressed again the second image is removed and the third image is added (so on and so fourth).  My question is would it be better to use a CCSpriteFrameCache or CCSprite?  Or is there some kind of alternative.

If anyone has a better way of doing this please let me know.  ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Sample Code:

```
-(void)buttons:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
if (CGRectContainsPoint(leftB.boundingBox, touchLocation) && tapP == YES && paused == NO) {
    if (count == 1)
    {
        isBOP = YES;
        count = 2;
    } else if (count == 3)
    {
        [bspriteSheet removeChild:_b cleanup:YES];
        [pspriteSheet removeChild:_p cleanup:YES];

        _p = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"p3.png"];
        [pspriteSheet addChild:_p];
        count = 4;
        _p.position = ccp(240, 215);

        _b = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"b2.png"];
        _b.position = ccp(240, 158);
        [bspriteSheet addChild:_b];
    }
if (CGRectContainsPoint(rightB.boundingBox, touchLocation) && tapP == YES && paused == NO) {
    if (count == 2)
    {
        [self removeChild:gb cleanup:YES];
        [pspriteSheet removeChild:_p cleanup:YES];

        _p = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"p2.png"];
        _p.position = ccp(240, 215);
        [pspriteSheet addChild:_p];

        _b = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"b1.png"];
        _b.position = ccp(240, 158);
        [bspriteSheet addChild:_b];

        count = 3;
    } else if (count == 4)
    {
        [bspriteSheet removeChild:_b cleanup:YES];
        [pspriteSheet removeChild:_p cleanup:YES];

        _p = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"p4.png"];
        [pspriteSheet addChild:_p];
        count = 5;
        _p.position = ccp(240, 215);

        _b = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"b3.png"];
        _b.position = ccp(240, 158);
        [bspriteSheet addChild:_b];
    }
```

Comment: Just a tip, use the pvr image format for sprites that don't need to be sharp or high resolution because they take up way less memory. Good luck on your first game!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the best practices document... they have a lot of details about the issue that you have.

[http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3abest_practices)

Consider using other image formats for your large images.  Using a PVRTC file would greatly cut down on your memory usage.